# How does the CSS mediaQuery works

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, media-queries

I need to know how the CSS media query works.
I mean, if I use `@media(min-width: 768px)`, does this function called every time the window is resized ?

Because I am wondering if I can use a Javascript `$(window).bind('resize orientationchange')` or if it is more resource intensive.

It is for add or remove a class to a div, an exemple :
http://jsfiddle.net/xbh28o08/

My goal is to enter in the HTML a data attribut which determine when the navbar has to collapse (data-breakpoint"768" for example). And I would get this breakpoint for make a responsive navbar automatically, without change any CSS. My idea was to do it with Javascript but it seems really not a good idea according to your answers

```
var widthScreen = $(window).width();


if (widthScreen > 768)
    $('nav').addClass('large');
else
    $('nav').addClass('small');


$(window).bind('resize orientationchange', function() {
    widthScreen = $(window).width();

    if (widthScreen > 768){
        $('nav').addClass('large');
        $('nav').removeClass('small');
    }
    else{
        $('nav').removeClass('large');
        $('nav').addClass('small');
    }
});
```

Comment: Give a read to this article http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 2):

to answer your first question: yes a media query does get called every time you do resize the window.

there is no need to add classes with javascript, I provided you with an example:

it does completely the same but no js needed. Its better to avoid using javascript when its not needed.

```css
nav{
  background: green;
}

@media(min-width: 768px){
    
    nav{
        background: red;
    }
}
```

```html
<nav>
 <ul>
  <li>Link 1</li>
  <li>Link 2</li>
 </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use css media queries instead of javascript as css is faster than javascript
As soon as Your device width is 768px all the css in that will be called and would overwrite the any other if exist
For more info you can check the link below
[Css Media Queries](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/css/introduction-to-css-media-queries.html)

Answer (score 0):

Media query will trigger only when particular point (width or height)  mentioned in your media query, whereas javascript resize will trigger at every pixel changed during resize. And, JS is more resource intensive IMO whereas CSS is not and faster. Have a [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

So, in your case, instead of removing and adding classes, have one class and override it's properties based on the screen size in your media query. Something like:

```
.my-class { width: 400px; }

@media(min-width: 768px){

    .my-class { width: 200px; }
}
```

OR

You can have 2 classes all the time, but only one will take effect based on the screen size. This way you don't override properties (which is a bit ugly, but, that's just me)

```
// screen <= 767
@media(max-width: 767px){
    .nav-small {
        width: 320px;    
    }
}
// screen >= 768
@media(min-width: 768px){
    .nav-large {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok that's what I thought. My goal is to enter in the HTML a data attribut (named data-breakpoint) which determine when the navbar has to collapse. And I would get this breakpoint for make a responsive navbar automatically, without change any CSS. My idea was to  do it with Javascript but it seems really not a good idea. I'm stuck haha

Answer (score 0):

A CSS media query will apply whenever the conditions in it are fulfilled (for instance, media screen and max-width of 768px), and be ignored whenever it is not. It applies to the window size and will update on resize. You can test this on this website by shrinking your browser.

Such a use-case (using the window resize event) is not recommended as it will trigger on **every** resize event. Not just when the resizing is finished, but also every tick between start and end. The only use case I know of is to add/remove classes, which is both not recommended, and also a downright CPU hog.